# Recursive type check using templates

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, type-traits

I've got a couple of type checking templates: `is_object` from `type_traits` and `isSupportedContainer` implemented the following way:

```
template <class T>
struct isSupportedContainer
    : public false_type {};

template <class T>
struct isSupportedContainer < list<T> >
    : public true_type {};

/*other containers*/
```

I want to make a recursive check `isSupported` applying itself not only to the container type, but also to the contained type. The current implementation:

```
// using std::__and_ and std::for from type_traits
template <class T>
struct isSupported
    : public __and_ < __or_ < is_object<T>, isSupportedContainer<T> >,
                      isSupported <T> > {};
```

When I call `isSupported < vector<int> >::value`, it generates a bunch of compilation errors (shortened):

```
In instantiation of 'struct std::__and_<...>, isSupportedContainer<std::vector<...> > >, isSupported<std::vector<...> > >':
required from 'struct isSupported<std::vector<int> >'
required from /*its call in main()*/
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::conditional<true, isSupported<std::vector<int> >, std::__or_<...>, isSupportedContainer<std::vector<...> > > >::type'
 struct __and_<_B1, _B2>
        ^
In /*file containing isSupported and isSupportedContainer*/:
error: declaration of 'std::conditional<true, isSupported<std::vector<int> >, std::__or_<...> >::type'
 struct isSupported
        ^
In function 'int main()':
error: 'value' is not a member of 'isSupported<std::vector<int> >'
 cout << isSupported < vector<int> >::value;
         ^
```

So, how can such a check be implemented?

Examples: assuming `list` and `vector` as supported classes `vector<list<int>>` is also supported and `vector<list<vector<string>>>` is not

UPD: a working version
UPD2: no, not working

```
template <class T>
struct isSupported
    : public isSupportedSimpleObject<T> {};    //is_object turned out to be a wrong thing

template <template<class> class T, class U>
struct isSupported < T<U> >
    : public __and_ < isSupportedContainer<T<U>>,
                      isSupported <U> > {};
```

Comment: You seem to use `isSupported<T>` in a definition of `isSupported`. Additionally, `std::is_object` probably won't do what you expect it to do.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's a mistake. About `is_object`: why? I expect it to let non-void fundamental types, arrays and pointers through. Enums and unions are also acceptable.

Comment: `is_object` lets *everything* through, including unsupported containers. It only filters out functions, references and `void`. If you want to support all non-container types and some containers, you will have a hard time distinguishing containers from non-containers. There's no distinction at the language level.

Comment: Just noticed that the asterisk in "class*" in the table about type categories at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/ means a remark. I thought it means a class pointer :) Thank you!

Comment: Other than the use of `std::is_object`, allow me to do a bit of shameless self publishing and offer you give my answer a look. I'm curious to know if it's on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably simplify the whole calculation if you use `enable_if` in the initial substitution.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <class T>
struct isSupportedContainer : std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct isSupportedContainer < std::list<T> > : std::true_type {};

template <class T>
struct isSupportedContainer < std::vector<T> > : std::true_type {};

template <class T, typename = void> // #1
struct isSupported : std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_object<T>::value> {};

template <class Cont> // #2
struct isSupported<Cont, typename std::enable_if<isSupportedContainer<Cont>::value>::type>
  : isSupported<typename Cont::value_type> {};


int main() {
    static_assert(isSupported<std::vector<int>>::value,"");
    static_assert(isSupported<std::vector<std::list<int>>>::value,"");
    static_assert(isSupported<std::string>::value,"");
    static_assert(!isSupported<int&>::value,"");
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/wGKEKq)

This technique (if it is indeed what you are after) is based on the principle for which `std::void_t` was added to C++17

The key points are as follows:

1. The primary template definition accepts two type parameters. the first is named `T`, and the other is unnamed and has a default type of `void`. This version simply checks your base case.
2. When you instantiate the template, the compiler matches the primary instance `isSupported<YourType, void>`.
   Now the compiler checks if there is any specialization that matches the argument types `<YourType, void>`, so it looks at the specialization that was provided. `std::enable_if` is used to determine it the type is in fact a supported container, and if such it returns `void`, and we match the types deduced originally `<YourType, void>`. Therefore the compiler takes the specialization as the better match, and we do a recursive check.
3. If however the type supplied is not a supported container, `std::enable_if` has no `type` member, and SFINAE kicks in. The substitution fails, and we return to the base case we found in (1), which does the basic check.

Comment: Seems to be the equivalent to what I added in UPD, but I can not understand nor find the exact meaning of `typename=void` and of the whole structure ._. Could you explain it?

Comment: @Alex, please see my edit. Let me know if anything needs clearing up.

Comment: @StoryTeller After a second thought. I think your solution nicely solves the question :-)

Comment: What are `integral_constant`s for here? They seem to do nothing

Comment: @Alex, `std::is_object` isn't guaranteed to inherit from `std::integral_constant` (although it probably does). I did it this way to ensure my struct definition does inherit from it (to ensure proper metaprogramming form), as well as capture the value of `std::is_object`. It's probably too much, but I like being explicit.

Comment: @Alex, I get what you mean now. In the specialization I could have just inherited directly from `isSupported` again.